# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'. Bing search

Tags: python

```
import requests
URL = "https://mykey:mykey@api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?$format=json&Query=%(query)s"
API_KEY = 'mykey'
def request(query, **params):
    query = ('%27'+query+ '%27')
    r = requests.get(URL % {'query': query}, auth=('', API_KEY))
    print r.content
    #return r.json()['d']['results']    
r = request("JasonBourne")
print r[0]['Url']
```

it generates the error i mentioned above for

```
print r[0]['Url']
```

The value of r.content is

```
{"d":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Web?Query=\u0027JasonBourne\u0027&$skip=0&$top=1","type":"WebResult"},"ID":"caac4e4d-b701-497a-ae61-f2b2993685d5","Title":"Jason Bourne - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia","Description":"Jason Charles Bourne is a fictional character and the protagonist of a series of novels by Robert Ludlum and subsequent film adaptations. He first appeared in the ...","DisplayUrl":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Bourne","Url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Bourne"},{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Web?Query=\u0027JasonBourne\u0027&$skip=1&$top=1","type":"WebResult"},"ID":"32688769-2490-470e-9903-8ea6b836ff97","Title":"JasonBourne.com","Description":"Welcome to Loscocco Media ... Created by author Robert Ludlum and brought to the silver screen with the face of Matt Damon, Jason Bourne is an enigmatic killer in ...","DisplayUrl":"jasonbourne.com","Url":"http://jasonbourne.com/"},{"__metadata":{"uri":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Web?Query=\u0027JasonBourne\u0027&$skip=2&$top=1","type":"WebResult"},"ID":"5db32b8f-2940-4542-a2e7-379e347201c3","Title":"Jason Bourne | The Bourne Identity | The Bourne Ultimatum | The ...","Description":"Jason Bourne is a CIA assassin & the hero of a trilogy of movies based on the books of Robert Ludlam; these are The Bourne Identity, Bourne Ultimatum, & Bourne Supremacy.","DisplayUrl":"jason-bourne.com","Url":"http://jason-bourne.com/"},{"__metadata":}
```

It's not the whole value, cause it's too big.

Comment: assert r[0] is not None

Comment: Why did you comment out `return r.json()['d']['results']`? That would at least have returned *something* (provided you got results in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function doesn't *return* anything. Printing is not the same thing as returning a value.

The default return value for a function is `None`, which causes your error. You want to return *something*, most likely `r.json()`:

```
def request(query, **params):
    query = ('%27'+query+ '%27')
    r = requests.get(URL % {'query': query}, auth=('', API_KEY))
    return r.json()
```

then loop over the results:

```
r = request("JasonBourne")
for res in r['d']['results']:
    print res['Url']
```

or collect them all in a list with a list comprehension:

```
r = request("JasonBourne")
urls = [res['Url'] for res in r['d']['results']]
```

giving you a list `urls`.

Comment: Thanks. How can i store access all the urls from one variable for r['Url']

Comment: @user2626758: Add them to a list you mean?

Comment: Right. I am including this in the function. And to access it i simply do 'for res in r'? Sorry im new to programming.

Comment: I used it instead of the `for` loop and `print` statement. The code works against the result of the `request()` function as defined by me in my answer.

Comment: Okay, can you just change your answer by including where to put the urls code and how to access it.

Comment: Nope i have included 
'for res in r['d']['results']:
        return res['Url']'
and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @user2626758: You are returning the **first** url, not the whole list. Use a list comprehension, as I have shown in my answer. A `return` **ends the function**, not return a list of result.

Comment: I've updated the other question, how bout you take a look at the code.